# Three.js: Show object only on one side of PlaneGeometry

Tags: three.js

I created a PlaneGeometry in Three.js and placed an object on top of it.
If I move the camera so that I can see the PlaneGeometry from below I can still see parts from the object on top. How can I define that the object is only seen from above the PlaneGeometry?

[Image from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of8Me.png)
[Image from below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLTvt.png)

```
// Creating PlaneGeometry
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 );
floorGeometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
var floorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '../img/wood-texture.jpg' );
floorTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
floorTexture.repeat.set(20, 20);
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var floor = new THREE.Mesh( floorGeometry, floorMaterial );
scene.add( floor );

// Creating object on top 
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x444444,wireframe: true});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
cube.position.set(0, 0.5, 0);
scene.add(cube);
```

Comment: As an option, try to set the cube a bit higher `cube.position.set(0, 0.51, 0);`

Comment: That also was my first thought. But if I zoom in I can see the gap. And I imagine that it will cause problems with the shadow casting later on.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Try setting your `floorMaterial` like this: `var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide, polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: 1, polygonOffsetUnits: 0.1 });` That should bump the floor plane slightly closer to the camera, but it might also have the negative effect of making the floor overlap the bottom of the cube when viewed from above.

Comment: @TheJim01 Tried it, didn't have any visible effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As workaround I set the floor lower. If I zoom in I can still see the gap but it seems to be the best / only solution.

```
floor.position.y = -0.5;
```